# How can I omit repeated parameters in functions?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I have a function f2 with a few arguments, and it is repeatedly used as shown below:

```
f2('data1.csv', par1='x', par2='y', par3='z')
f2('data2.csv', par1='x', par2='y', par3='z')
f2('data3.csv', par1='x', par2='y', par3='z')
```

Is there a way to code this part - `par1='x', par2='y', par3='z'` - without typing it out for every function call?

In a particular case the function paste has default `sep=" "`. I know I can suppress this by setting sep parameter as shown below:

```
formals(paste)$sep <- ""
print(paste('foo','spam'))
```

But this might not work for all parameters. I tried to set the given format of date, but this leads to an error:

```
formals(as.POSIXct)$format <- "%d.%m.%Y"
print(as.POSIXct('3.12.2022'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you could do is define a new function that only takes the file or a function with default parameters:

```
f3 <- function(dat_file){
   f2(dat_file, par1='x', par2='y', par3='z')
}

f3('data1.csv')
f3('data2.csv')
f3('data3.csv')
```

---

```
f4 <- function(dat_file, par1='x', par2='y', par3='z'){
   f2(dat_file, par1 = par1, par2 = par2, par3 = par3)
}

f4('data1.csv')
f4('data2.csv')
f4('data3.csv')
```